# How do you use one thread to do multiple timed actions rather than multiple timers

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, thread-sleep

The overlook of my project is creating an interactive tutorial.  I am playing a sound clip and at certain times during the sound clip i want certain actions to take place(Ex. Highlight a button).  I have come up with a solution but i feel it is eating up a lot of CPU.  The solution i came up with is setting up each individual timer for each individual action that will take place during the sound clip.  I foresee this crunching down on the CPU eventually if i start making say 50 different timers for 50 different actions which is making 50 different threads.

Here is a snippet of my current code using these timers;

```
private void Label_FindingPart_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        sound.Source = new Uri(@"C:\SomeSound.wav");
        sound.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;  
        sound.Play();

        Timer_Logistics_Button(1000);
        Timer_Logistics_Window(1500);
        Timer_MMBE_Button(2000);
        Timer_MMBE_Window(2500);
    }
    //Timer initalized
    private void Timer_Logistics_Button(int interval_length)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.AutoReset = false;
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(On_Timer_Logistics_Button);
        aTimer.Interval = interval_length;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
    //Action when the Elapsed event is raised.
    private void On_Timer_Logistics_Button(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            Button_Logistics.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        });

    }
    //Timer initalized
    private void Timer_Logistics_Window(int interval_length)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.AutoReset = false;
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(On_Timer_Logistics_Window);
        aTimer.Interval = interval_length;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
    //Action when the Elapsed event is raised.
    private void On_Timer_Logistics_Window(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            Image_SAP_Main.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Image_SAP_Main_Logistics.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Button_Logistics.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

        });

    }
    //Timer initalized
    private void Timer_MMBE_Button(int interval_length)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer bTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        bTimer.AutoReset = false;
        bTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(On_Timer_MMBE_Button);
        bTimer.Interval = interval_length;
        bTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
    //Action when the Elapsed event is raised.
    private void On_Timer_MMBE_Button(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            Button_MMBE.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        });
    }
    //Timer initalized
    private void Timer_MMBE_Window(int interval_length)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer bTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        bTimer.AutoReset = false;
        bTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(On_Timer_MMBE_Window);
        bTimer.Interval = interval_length;
        bTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
    //Action when the Elapsed event is raised.
    private void On_Timer_MMBE_Window(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            Image_SAP_Main_Logistics.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Button_MMBE.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Image_SAP_MMBE.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        });
    }
```

My other idea is to create one thread and have it start the same time as sound.play(). This one thread would have multiple thread.sleep() statements for the wait time between each action.  So in retrospect it would look like this:

```
    Step A: Play();
    Step B: Thread.Start();
    Step C: Thread.sleep(1000);
    Step D: ACTION;
    Step E: Thread.sleep(500);
    Step F: ACTION;
    Step G: Thread.sleep(1200);
    Step H: ACTION;
    Step I: Thread.Stop();
```

The code below is as far as i could get with threads i was having a hard time going from step D to step E.  I also still need to find out how to properly stop my thread.  The code below is what i was able to fester up:

```
     System.Threading.Thread Tutorial_Thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
        delegate()
        {
            // Do the work here.
            Thread.Sleep(5000);


            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(
            delegate()
            {
                // Invoke any updates to the GUI here.
                Button_Logistics.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            }
         ));
        }
         ));
        sound.Play();
        Tutorial_Thread.Start();
```

Once the thread is through it will go back to the start of the thread and perform that thread.sleep(5000). I am not sure how to change the sleep time and action for each rotation through the thread.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and i hope i made question clear and understandable.
I am using Visual Studio 2012, C#, WPF.

Comment: You should just use multiple `DispatcherTimer`s instead of invoking back onto the UI thread. It will only ever use a single thread (the dispatcher's thread) to service callbacks.

Comment: Side note: timers and especially `Sleep` is unreliable way to synchronize two or more sequences of "events". Both give no guarantees on completion on time. You maybe better off checking what should be happening periodically (i.e. 50ms) in relation to your "tutorial" scenario rather than relying on timers/Sleep to fire off at very particular moments of time.

Answer (score 0):

A thread executes code then exits, it doesn't loop unless your code loops.  In the sample you posted the thread waits for 5 seconds, changes the button's visibility, then exits.

So... since you have a defined sequence of actions, you could write it like this:

```
Thread Tutorial_Thread = new Thread(() => 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => do_step_d());
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => do_step_f());
        Thread.Sleep(1200);
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => do_step_h());
    });
Tutorial_Thread.Start();
```

The thread will proceed through the statements, pausing at the `Sleep` calls, executing the various step methods, then exit.

This is a simplistic example of course.  Rather than writing a static piece of code that only executes a single sequence, and writing similar code for each different sequence, you'd be better off figuring out a scheduling system that you can queue event sequences onto... possibly using **mike z**'s suggestion to handle the timing.

Answer (score 0):

Spinning off multiple things in sequence with delays between certain pieces can be addressed by using a thread and Thread.Sleep but it can be problematic as it introduces a definite wait, not to mention it ties that thread up for the duration of that wait.

Microsoft introduced the Task system as the de-facto high-level replacement of direct Thread access.

An example would be:

```
Play();
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        action_1();
        await Task.Delay(500);
        action_2();
        await Task.Delay(1200);
        action_3();
    });

// Task start returns immediately
Console.ReadLine();
```

This approach has a number of advantages over Thread.Sleep, Tasks are scheduled and the thread management is taken care of for you, tasks also have composition functions (ContinueWith etc) see the docs for more info.

The biggest advantage though is that by making the task itself an async method (using the new C# async / await), each of the times you're waiting on the delays the underlying thread can be used for other work so you're not starving the system of a thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is with `async`:

```
private async void Label_FindingPart_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    sound.Source = new Uri(@"C:\SomeSound.wav");
    sound.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;  
    sound.Play();

    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Button_Logistics.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    await Task.Delay(500);
    Image_SAP_Main.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    Image_SAP_Main_Logistics.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Button_Logistics.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    await Task.Delay(500);
    Button_MMBE.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    await Task.Delay(500);
    Image_SAP_Main_Logistics.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    Button_MMBE.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    Image_SAP_MMBE.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

If you need to stop it, just use a `CancellationTokenSource` and pass its `CancellationToken` into all the `Task.Delay` calls.